# Use variables parsed from config files in SQL query

Tags: python, sql, configparser

Here is how the variables are parsed from the config file :

```
soc_code = tuple(config.get('MyScript', 'soc_code').split(','))
genre_code = tuple(config.get('MyScript', 'genre_code').split(','))
```

Here is my sql query :

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(''' 
SELECT SOC_NAME, GENRE_NAME FROM DATA WHERE SOC_CODE IN %s AND GENRE_CODE IN %s
''' % (genre_code, soc_code) ,conn)
```

The content of the config file look like this:

```
soc_code = CODE1, CODE2
genre_codes = GCODE1, GCODE2
```

I always end up with a formatting error.

Comment: _I always end up with a formatting error_ Show us the whole error message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/scripts_prod/from __future__ import print_function.py", line 58, in <module>
    sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(''' 
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting